# Как в своем магазине настроить прием криптовалют? (BTC, LTC, ETH)

Tags: bitcoin

Нет ли общего способа, чтобы принимать эти три валюты на своем сервисе без установки холодного кошелька?

Comment: Во все тяжкие?)

Comment: Не, просто у меня есть казино-бот в телеграмме, я хочу чтобы он принимал криптовалюты =))

Comment: Один из самых простых вариантов воспользоваться процесинговым платежным сервисом.
я использую https://biwse.com/